GoRouter always shows only one page
Problem: My app always displays the login screen regardless of whatever kind of navigation I make (like setting the initial location to another page, context.push, context.go, etc). I have implemented a redirecting function in the authentication system that redirects user back to the login page if they are unauthenticated but that does not seem to be the culprit (the two print statements: "authState changes" and "Redirect!" did not get called when I pressed the navigating button).
My main.dart file:
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/models/cart.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/routes/app_route_config.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  // Referesh GoRouter configuration every time authState changes (Authentication guaranteed)
  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {

    print("authState changes");

    MyAppRouter.router.refresh();
  });

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<Cart>(create: (context) => Cart()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
              create: (context) => AuthService())
        ],
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.grey)),
          routerConfig: MyAppRouter.router,
        ));
  }
}


My App router configs:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/models/shopee_tile.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/pages/item_page.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/pages/signup_page.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/routes/app_route_constants.dart';
import 'package:sneaker_app/services/auth_service.dart';

class MyAppRouter {
  static final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: "/login",
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
          name: MyAppRouteConstants.homeRouteName,
          path: "/",
          builder: (context, state) => HomePage()),
      GoRoute(
          name: MyAppRouteConstants.itemRouteName,
          path: "/item/:id",
          builder: (context, state) {
            ShopeeTile item = state.extra as ShopeeTile;
            return ItemPage(
              id: int.parse(state.pathParameters["id"]!),
              item: item,
            );
          }),
      GoRoute(
          name: MyAppRouteConstants.loginRouteName,
          path: "/login",
          builder: (context, state) => LoginPage()),
      GoRoute(
          name: MyAppRouteConstants.signupRouteName,
          path: "/signup",
          builder: (context, state) => SignupPage()),
    ],
    redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) async {
      final bool loggedIn =
          Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false).user != null;
      final bool loggingIn = state.matchedLocation == "/login";

      print("Redirect!");

      if (!loggedIn) return "/login";
      if (loggingIn) return "/";
      // no need to redirect at all
      return null;
    },
  );
}


I can ensure that the constants in MyAppRouteConstants match their path
Here is the button widget on the login page
TextButton(
              child: Text('Sign up'),
              onPressed: () {
                context.pushNamed(MyAppRouteConstants.signupRouteName);
              },
            ),

I tried to debug the problem by putting print statements but I couldn't find out why the app only stuck to the login page and did not navigate at all.

With the code snippets you provided, my first guess is that the problem lies in the following line:
routerConfig: MyAppRouter.router,

Since you apparently have built-in authentication to decide where the user lands, the build method of MyApp is being called again. However, due to this line, a new GoRouter object is being created because you are assigning a new object to router in MyAppRouter. And this config then takes the LoginPage (/login) as the initialLocation.
As a test, try storing your GoRouter object in your main.dart file as a global variable:
GoRouter myRouter = GoRouter(...)

Now pass this variable as routerConfig. This might already be the solution.

Now I got "Redirect!" printed to the console :O even though my authentication status never changed

I guess redirect is called every time you navigate to a page, also if it's your initial page. So if you start your application, you navigate to /login. This navigation should call your logic inside your redirect.

Besides, I have a question. I tag the GoRouter myRouter in the appRouterConfigs class as static, and I have read on the Internet that if a variable is tagged as static, then there is only one "instance" of that variable which is accessible by every instance. So why when the build method gets called multiple times, along with many more new instances of MyAppRouterConfigs being created, there are different instances of "myRouter" getting assigned? Don't they all refer to the same static router variable in that class?

It is only a single instance. But every time you call build it jumps into MyAppRouter.router line. This checks what behind router is. And in your case you always create a new instance of a GoRouter and write it in your static field. So every time you call build you create a new GoRouter which can be used anywhere in your project. You don't want to create an instance every time you call build, you only wan't to create it a single time. And this instance should be used in your code if you need it.
